# not getting last key in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I am using a array for status in my application

```
$status =array("New lead", "Email reply", "Phone reply" ,"In conversation", "Invoice generated", "Full payment", "Partial payment", "Decline");
```

and using `foreach` loop to generate `HTML`, below is the code.

```
foreach ($status as $value){
   $selected = (int)$posts->status == key($status) ?  "selected" : "";
   echo '<option value="'.key($status).'" '.$selected .'>'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

and the output I am getting is

```
   <option value="1">New lead</option>
   <option value="2">Email reply</option>
   <option value="3">Phone reply</option>
   <option value="4">In conversation</option>
   <option value="5" selected="">Invoice generated</option>
   <option value="6">Full payment</option>
   <option value="7">Partial payment</option>
   <option value="">Decline</option>
```

I am not getting last `key` for Decline status. Need your help.

Comment: test this code   $selected = (int)$posts->status == key($status) ?  "selected='selected'" : "";

Comment: @aje https://eval.in/779392 -  How did you get other keys? :)

Comment: All answers on this page are FLAWED except for Amir Mohsen's.  Please switch the green tick to his answer asap.  The rest of the answers will get your selected value wrong 100% of the time.  Load and run this demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8c004a525989e86fda73c864faea8065ebc3fdd then use your browser's Find tool to search for `selected`, then have a look at the output box to see how the other answers fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($status as $key => $value){
   $selected = (int)$posts->status == key($status) ?  "selected" : "";
   echo '<option value="'.$key.'" '.$selected .'>'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Downvote.  See my comment on the question for a demonstration of the fault.  Amir got it right because he tested his solution and set up an online demo.  Please delete your answer when it is "un-accepted" because correcting it will create a duplicate post and that is just page bloat.

Answer (score 3):

This code must be work :

```
foreach ($status as $key => $value){
   $selected = $posts->status == $key ?  "selected='selected'" : "";
   echo '<option value="'. $key.'" '.$selected .'>'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

if you want to use key function you must use while loop with current:

```
while ($value = current($status)) {
    $selected = (int)$posts->status == key($status) ?  "selected" : "";
    echo '<option value="'.key($status).'" '.$selected .'>'.$value.'</option>';
    next($status);
}
```

read this php reference:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

code : https://eval.in/779400

result :

```
<option value="0" selected>New lead</option>
<option value="1" >Email reply</option>
<option value="2" >Phone reply</option>
<option value="3" >In conversation</option>
<option value="4" >Invoice generated</option>
<option value="5" >Full payment</option>
<option value="6" >Partial payment</option>
<option value="7" >Decline</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the pointer of the $status array is already moved to the next item, so instead of getting the key for $value, you will get the key to the next value in the array. More details:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php#114905

Comment: This answer should be a comment on the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
$status =array("New lead", "Email reply", "Phone reply" ,"In conversation", "Invoice generated", "Full payment", "Partial payment", "Decline");
 echo '<select>';
foreach ($status as $key => $value){
   $selected = (int)$posts->status == key($status) ?  "selected" : "";
   echo '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$selected .'>'.$value.'</option>';
}
 echo '</select>';
```

Array First Value Key Is 0 because array index always Start 0

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Downvote.  See my comment on the question for a demonstration of the fault.  Amir got it right because he tested his solution and set up an online demo.  Please delete your answer because correcting it will create a duplicate post and that is just page bloat.